# Fetching data from nba.com/stats/transactions/

Tags: nba-api

Is there a method in the nba-api package which allows querying the endpoint for data regarding transactions between teams (https://www.nba.com/stats/transactions/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't look, but no need for that package. Just get that data directly:

```
import pandas as pd  
import requests

url = 'https://www.nba.com/stats/js/data/playermovement/NBA_Player_Movement.json'
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData['NBA_Player_Movement']['rows'])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df)
     Transaction_Type     TRANSACTION_DATE  ... Additional_Sort        GroupSort
0             Signing  2021-04-21T00:00:00  ...             0.0  Signing 1039411
1             Signing  2021-04-21T00:00:00  ...             0.0  Signing 1039412
2             Signing  2021-04-21T00:00:00  ...             0.0  Signing 1039413
3             Signing  2021-04-21T00:00:00  ...             0.0  Signing 1039414
4             Signing  2021-04-20T00:00:00  ...             0.0  Signing 1039383
              ...                  ...  ...             ...              ...
4581          Signing  2015-07-02T00:00:00  ...             0.0   Signing 944820
4582          Signing  2015-07-02T00:00:00  ...             0.0   Signing 944876
4583          Signing  2015-07-02T00:00:00  ...             0.0   Signing 944877
4584          Signing  2015-07-02T00:00:00  ...             0.0   Signing 944878
4585          Signing  2015-07-01T00:00:00  ...             0.0   Signing 944801

[4586 rows x 9 columns]
```